# xamarin ios reset detail page

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I've two page in xamarin.ios. FirstPage and SeconDPage(Detail) with a counter inside. I've an unwind segue from SecondPage to FirstPage. The problem is when return to FirstPage and renter in SecondPage the page it'is not reset but the counter continues in background. How to reset the page?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your UI hierarchy screenshot in your storyboard? Is there a navigation controller, and you navigate to the first page from second page?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I navigate to second page from first page, but when I return to the first page, the second page remain in execution in background.

Comment: Did you have a NSTimer running in the viewcontroller? If so, you have to invalidate it in `ViewWillDisappear`.